# How do I avoid the white label error(404) on localhost:8080?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, localhost, white-labelling

I have been looking around here and in other forums for hours and I still haven't found what I am doing wrong. I have built a simple Spring-Boot application with MongoDB and I have no errors in the console when i run it but i keep getting the white label error no matter what I do. My main and controller classes are in different packages but I have used @ComponentScan. I have also added web app folder thinking it would fix it but apparently that wasn't the issue. I have also added all the necessary mappings to the controller class. These are the most common solutions I've seen but I still get the same error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.5.RELEASE
 

com.example
Kamerat
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Kamerat
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[Screenshot of Controller class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE32z.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this error  because there is no defaut webPage for spring boot
[Screenshot with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cRhE.png)

To fix it , you just need to add a simple html file (index.html) in you sr/main/resources/statics directory

[Screenshot of the config to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrKQK.png)

Then you will have :

[Screenshot after the fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOqs5.png)

Comment: Thank you for your help! This fixed my problem!

Answer (score -1):

Use @RestController at you web controller and you must have following dependency added in your pom.xml

if possible please share your web controller and pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I checked and i already have that dependency. I tried adding all of my code to the question but kept getting errors and couldnt post. I'll add it right now, and thanks

Comment: @ComponentScan({"com.example.demo"}) please like this looks like it si not creating bean.